# Combine Two Filter Functions in Excel

Tags: excel, excel-formula

Column A has some data which I see in column E by formula `=FILTER(A1:A27,A1:A27<>"")` Similarly column C has some data which I see `=FILTER(C1:C27,C1: C27 <> "")` appears in f. Now if I want to look up column G through a formula for both columns A & C, how to solve it in a formula?

Note: The data in columns B and D will not affect the results

Combine Two Filter Functions in Excel

Comment: `VSTACK()` or `HSTACK()` is used to combine results. You can use multiple condition inside `FILTER()` function for more criteria. Post few sample data to your post.

Comment: If its only excluding the blanks, then you could have tried using `TOCOL()` instead of `FILTER()` and use `VSTACK()` or `HSTACK()` accordingly as per your requirements. So that said, the formula could be : `VSTACK(TOCOL(A1:A27,1),TOCOL(C1:C27,1))` this will stack one upon the other or `HSTACK(TOCOL(A1:A27,1),TOCOL(C1:C27,1))` while this will merge adjacent to each other. Or, for stacking this is succinct i believe `=TOCOL((A1:A27,C1:C27),1)`

Comment: With newer functions it is easier, One more approach would be `=LET(X,VSTACK(A1:A27,C1:C27),FILTER(X,X<>""))`

Comment: please post some example data with desired output. That would help us to better understand your problem.

Comment: Do you have some sample data with expected output? Especially the part where you want to lookup a value from column G:G.

Comment: @MayukhBhattacharya =TOCOL((A1:A27,C1:C27),1) and VSTACK(TOCOL(A1:A27,1),TOCOL(C1:C27,1)) worked great but now if I want to retrieve only unique data,  What will be the formula ?

Comment: @Alauddiin wrap within `UNIQUE()` function

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As mentioned above in comments and as OP also confirmed, it worked for them, hence posting it as answer.

[image]

---

For the said post, formula can be used :

```
=VSTACK(TOCOL(A1:A27,1),TOCOL(C1:C27,1))
```

---

Or,

```
=TOCOL((A1:A27,C1:C27),1)
```

---

Also if you are looking to get Unique values from the returned array then you can wrap the array within an `UNIQUE()` function.

---

Comment: Supper.... that's amazing. i was looking for this solution @Mayukh Bhattacharya